# Ubuntu - permanently remove ~/Videos and ~/Public

Tags: ubuntu

I've deleted the folders, but every time I sign back in they're recreated. I've edited `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and removed the offending lines, but they're replaced when I log back in! The file say's it's auto-generated by `/usr/bin/xdg-user-dirs-update`, but that seems to be a dead end.

Comment: I deleted the user but that particular user's name is coming at the ubuntu 10.04 lts login prompt and not getting deleted from there. please let me know how to achieve this. thx.

Answer (score 33):

Three files control the "personal special folders" behaviour:

- `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` - allow the user to specify a custom *path* for the special folders. So you can have you `Music` folder in, say, "$HOME/My Music", or "/datapartition/mp3". Its does *not* allow you to "disable" those folders. If you delete one line (or the whole file), default values will be used, as you have already noticed.
- `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` (overrided by `~/.config/user-dirs.conf`) - Allows you to enable or disable the automatic folder (re-)creation. If you set `enabled=False`, either globally or for your own user only, special folders will not be re-created at login anymore in case  you delete or rename the folders.
- `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`- Global template for folders path and name. This is the file read when `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is re-created. Be aware that changing default names will prevent folder names to be localized (translated) if you change your Language/Locale.

By the way, the service you disabled was just the daemon that would offer to rename the folders in case you changed your Language/Locale.

Answer (score 22):

Your problem has been explained at the [software wiki](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/#settings)

> **Settings**
>
> Sysadmins can configure things by editing /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf. At
>   the moment there are only two settings, you can disable the whole
>   thing, and you can specify the charset encoding used for filenames.
>   They can also set or change the default directories and their initial
>   values in /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults.
>
> $(XDG_CONFIG_HOME)/user-dirs.dirs specifies the current set of
>   directories for the user. This file is in a shell format, so its easy
>   to access from a shell script. This file can also be modified by users
>   (manually or via applications) to change the directories used. **Note:
>   To disable a directory, point it to the homedir. If you delete it it
>   will be recreated on the next login.**

So your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` could  be modified as

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"
```

Answer (score 7):

On at least Ubuntu 18.10, you can just remove the directories and run the following command in a terminal:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

The entries will be reassigned to home and disappear from the list under Files.

Comment: Works on ```Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)``` i.e. 20.04 dev

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a daemon that creates those folders, check the startup preferences, its on the system menu i believe, you can easily disable that feature.

Comment: the only thing i can find that looks like it could be it is `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update - Update common folders names to match current locale`, which is disabled

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xdg-user-dirs*
```

Comment: How is this better than other answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try install Ubuntu Tweak... under "Personal"+"Default Folder Locations" tab: you can change the location of the folders to wherever you wish or you can just have them all pointing to the same directory (i.e. /home/user/)